# Youtube pop up not working on windows but is on mac and ios, DESPERATE

Tags: javascript, ios, css, youtube, popup

I know this is not the done thing, but I have been trying to work this out now for 2 months and I need it ready for the first of January, on my website www.mildenhire.com/bigsmile. The youtube pop up iframe is not appearing on Opera, Firefox, IE or any other however it works on Safari. I believe it may be something to do with the Javascript.

Could somebody please have a look for me, this is shear desperation asking this now.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide me some code of popup?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20427537

Comment: the link above was my previous post where nobody could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may depend on browser rather than OS. I am on a PC right now, and left-clicking the YouTube popup link works perfectly on Safari, but not in Chrome, Firefox, IE, or Opera.

However, I get this type of script error in Inspector about 15-20 times when viewing the site in Chrome.

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.mildenhire.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://apis.google.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

Interestingly, I can still right click on your link and open it in a new window, only left-clicking does not work. Perhaps these errors are somehow blocking the javascript YouTube popup? I hope this can at least point you in the right direction.

---

**UPDATE:** Just to confirm, left-clicking on the button is what's causing the error above, registering 1 error per click. However, [it might be safe to ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399915/google-plus-button-code-warns-unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-in-ch?rq=1).

In Firefox, clicking the button returns this:

> Error: Permission denied to access property 'nodeType'

The common denominator I see with both error messages is **line 13 of plugins.js**, however [that line is incredibly long and I can't find anything meaningful in it](http://pastebin.com/FBRBAgGj) (JS is not my strongest area, to be honest).

But, since no one else has answered yet, what I would try is temporarily disabling the script that includes line 539 below, which contains the origin "https://apis.google.com" and see if the popup begins working correctly.

```
po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
```

I may be far off in reasoning that this is the problem, so I encourage someone who knows JavaScript better to point us in the right direction. However, I do have a hunch that it is connected to the pop up script being "blocked."

Otherwise -- I hate to suggest this, but since you're desperate -- would it be possible to use a plain html or non-js/jQuery method to open the YouTube window? Good luck!

Comment: thanks guys, I will keep on experimenting, but I simply cant find the answer and I have 4 years experience in design!! I think it may be the apis.google.com but I have never had this error before

Comment: Could this be the error? My JS for the google.apis is below.

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yes, this is certainly a tricky problem. I updated my answer above with more information and some suggestions. I'm not a JavaScript expert, so I'm sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: how do you mean  use plain html?